# Ubuntu 12.10 not working with Samsung ME40B/CY-TM40

Tags: usb, 12.10, touchscreen, samsung

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I'm trying to get it to work with a Samsung ME40B with the CY-TM40 touch screen.  The audio and visual output work fine with the HDMI connection.  The CY-TM40 connects via USB, but Ubuntu does not detect it.  I've verified the USB ports are working with other devices.

I installed the tool Calibrate Touchscreen, but it only returns:

> ```
> Error: No calibratable devices found.
> ```

A Samsung tech indicated standard HID drivers should work.  Does anyone have any suggestions for enhanced drivers, or tools that might help?

Thanks in advance.

PS.

The screen does show up in `/proc/bus/input/devices`

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1870 Product=010d Version=0111    
N: Name="Nexio Touch Device(HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0400-06"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input0   
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input14   
U: Uniq=  
H: Handlers=event2 js0  
B: PROP=2  
B: EV=b  
B: KEY=0  
B: ABS=2738000 3
```

and in `Xorg.0.log`

```
root@efsd01:/var/log# cat Xorg.0.log | grep -i nexio | more  
[     3.955] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Nexio Touch Device(HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0400-06  (/dev/input/event2)  
[     3.955] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Nexio Touch Device(HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0400-06  (/dev/input/js0)  
[    33.275] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Nexio Touch Device(HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0400-06  (/dev/input/js0)  
[    33.275] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Nexio Touch Device(HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0400-06  (/dev/input/event2)  
[  1528.357] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Nexio Touch Device(HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0400-06  (/dev/input/js0)  
[  1528.358] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Nexio Touch Device(HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0400-06  (/dev/input/event2)
```

But it does not show up in `xinput list`:

```
root@efsd01:/var/log# xinput list  
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
root@efsd01:/var/log#
```

Comment: Could you link to the files? Kind regards jesper

Comment: I am exactly in the same situation here so I was wondering if you could tell me how you got it done? thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is a firmware update needed to get the touch screen to work.  Samsung directed me to a set of files which needed to be run under Windows to upgrade the firmware.  The touch screen is now working with Ubuntu 12.10 for single touch operations.

The update is from Nexio - the touch screen overlay manufacturer. The updater application is called nxHIDcon and it is a Windows only application. You need to install the updater on a Windows machine and use that to push the firmware update to the touch screen. The updater application can be obtained here:

[NexioDownload Site](http://inexio.co.kr/07_download/download02.html)

You will also need a firmware file specific to your screen.

I have some of the driver updates including those for

- ATI0320
- ATI0400
- ATI0460
- ATI0550

These were provided by a Samsung integration engineer.